# get class considering data from json

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs

I want to change the class, considering what kind of data comes from json.

here i get json from backend

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
    $http({method: 'GET', 
           url: 'http://api.something.com/api/v1/inventory/?format=json'})
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.info = data; // response data 
    });

    //here i am trying to change the class

    this.getClass = function() {
        if(info.objects === "good condition")
            return "good";  
        } else {
            return "bad";
    };

});
```

and at my template i have like this. Trying to change the class with .getClass function , bet i kind a know that `info.objects` is not correct to check with "good condition"

```
<tr ng-repeat="inventory in info.objects">
    <td>{{inventory.name}}</td>
    <td>{{inventory.description}}</td>
    <td>{{inventory.location}}</td>
    <td ng:class="getClass($index)">{{inventory.status}}</td>
    <td>{{inventory.category}}</td>
</tr>
```

json file where i get status data from

```
{
  meta: {
  limit: 20,
  next: null,
  offset: 0,
  previous: null,
  total_count: 1
 },
  objects: [
      {
         count: 2,
          created: "2014-02-20T09:01:15.285510",
          description: "Camelion 2300mAh",
          id: 1,
          location: "IT nodala",
          name: "Baterija AA",
          published: true,
          resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/1",
          slug: "baterija-aa",
          status: "good condition"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should try something like `info.objects[0].status === "good condition"`. As `objects` is an array, you need to use indexer to fetch first element and then compare with `status` field.

Comment: i am doing like this `this.getClass = function() {
  if(info.objects[0].status === "good condition"){
   alert("check");
  }
 };` but it doesnt allert when i refresh the page

Comment: You should try with `$scope.info` instead of `info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use conditional `ng-class` like this:

```
<td ng-class="{'good condition':'good', 'bad condition':'bad'}[inventory.status]">{{inventory.status}}</td>
```

Working [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/E4JGM/3/).